# How to generate random sampling in python . with integers. with sum and size given

Tags: python, numpy, random

Is there a direct function or any another way in python where I can generate random integers for my given size and I want to specify sum of those numbers as well.

For example.
I want to generate 7 numbers whose sum is 341.

Can I also specify mean for this. Like 7 numbers with mean 49 and sum 341. (optional)

Comment: Yeah, you can do whatever you like as long as you start with some code.

Comment: I do have code wait I will post

Comment: draw 6, choose the last one to be the diff of sum(your6) to your target value.

Comment: How can you have a mean of `165` by definition if it sums to `341` and there are `7` elements then the mean is `48.71`.

Comment: @AChampion sorry my mistake i have corrected it

Comment: You have no need to specify a mean - `7` numbers adding up to `341` will always have a mean of `48.71`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`random.gauss`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/random.html#random.gauss) to generate 6 numbers around a `mean` with a certain standard deviation (closeness) and as per @PatrickArtner suggestion construct the 7th one, e.g. using `3` standard devs from mean:

```
In []:
import random
vals = [int(random.gauss(341/7, 3)) for _ in range(6)]
vals.append(341 - sum(vals))
vals, sum(vals), sum(vals)/7

Out[]:
([47, 47, 48, 48, 54, 50, 47], 341, 48.714285714285715)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this code would probably do decent job:

```
_sum = 341
n = 7
Argentina = np.random.multinomial(_sum, np.ones(n)/n, size=1)[0]
print (Argentina)
[44 46 42 52 53 50 54]
```

Comment: You should have probably posted this with your question, but it does what you want - what is your question?

Comment: @AChampion My question was i wanted 7 random numbers with sum 341 and values close to mean. I did not have this code when i asked question found this later.

Comment: What does 'close to the mean' mean? How close? BTW that wasn't what you asked in your question.